# Using union / structs to create generalized list objects in pure C

Tags: c, gcc, struct, casting, unions

Linked lists are a fundamentally useful building block for many programming problems.  The following should look familiar:

```
typedef struct _list {
  struct _list *_next;
} list_t;

#define NULL_LIST ((list_t *)NULL)

void list_push(list_t *element, list_t **list_head);
list_t *list_pop(list_t **list_head);
list_t *list_next(list *list);
int list_length(list_t *list);
```

I'd like to use the above routines to manipulate other kinds of objects, assuming that the first slot of those objects is a `list_t *` link.  That is, I'd like to use `list_push()`, `list_pop()`, `list_length()` functions on other things that are defined like:

```
typedef struct _linked_buffer {
  list_t *_next;
  uint8_t _bufffer[80];
} linked_buffer_t;

typedef struct _pair {
  list_t *_next;
  void *_head;
} pair_t;
```

... etc.  My guarantee is that all these other "classes" share a _link slot in the first position.

So my question: is there a way to assure the C compiler that `linked_buffer_t` and `pair_t` are a "a kind of" `list_t` so that I don't have to use casting every time I want to use list operations on them?

I could create macros that hide the casting:

```
#define LIST_PUSH(el, head) list_push((list_t *)el, (list_t **)head)
```

but I'm wondering if there's a better approach with a clever use of `union` and `struct` constructs that would eliminate the need for casting everything.

Comment: Names starting with underscore at file scope are always reserved for the implementation in all name-spaces. Using them in user-code invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you are open to extensions, have a look at gcc `-fplan9-extensions`. The macros are not a good idea, they complicate debugging.

Comment: `#define LIST_PUSH(el, head) list_push((list_t *)el, (list_t **)head)` would be no different than using `void list_push(void *element, void **list_head);` and doing the casting internally.

Comment: One way to do it would be to define the headers of push pop etc to use void* instead of list_t* and list_t**. Since a pointer to any type is implicitly casted to void* you can eliminate the need to cast. Similar for return.

Comment: "Pure C" is a non-term.

Comment: @n.m. Good point!  I removed the "C" tag and changed it to "gcc".

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya "Since a pointer to any type is implicitly casted to void* ...", has an exception:  Function pointers may not fit in a `void *`.

Comment: @chux Ah yes! A *data pointer* in this case.

Comment: @fearless_fool C provides `_Generic`.  If you are willing to work with a limited list of defined types (`int, short, char *, double,...`) instead of all possible types `struct foo *, volatile double *, ...`, a wrapper employing `_Generic` will handle the proliferation of `(casts)`.

Comment: No need for `_Generic`, I think: GCC already provides `__typeof__`, and we can exploit C11 6.7.2.1p15 for the polymorphism. The downside is an extra parameter (generated and supplied by the macros) to the functions.

Answer (score 2):

A `union` will allow a degree of type-punning as long as all of the structs contained within contain the same initial set of fields.

For example:

```
typedef struct _generic_list {
  struct _generic_list *_next;
  char type;
} generic_list_t;

typedef struct _linked_buffer {
  generic_list_t *_next;
  char type;
  uint8_t _bufffer[80];
} linked_buffer_t;

typedef struct _pair {
  generic_list_t *_next;
  char type;
  void *_head;
} pair_t;

typedef union _list {
    generic_list_t generic_list;
    linked_buffer_t buffer;
    pair_t pair;
}
```

Because all members of the union have a `generic_list_t *` as the first element and a `char` as the second, you can safely access those elements in any member of the union.

The `type` field is a flag that will let you know which of the union members contains meaningful data for its other fields.  You'll need to set that field by convention.

Comment: There are other ways to implement runtime typing without adding a type field, e.g. all `pair_t` can be allocated from one known memory block and all `linked_buffer_t` from another.  (Did I mention this is for an embedded system with no malloc()?  My bad...)  Aside from that nit, great answer!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that each instance of such a generic linked lists will store only one kind of "class" you can use a pointer to void `void*` as second member of the list struct.

```
typedef struct _list  
{
    struct _list *_next;
    void * pData; 
} list_t;
```

The typical operations on linked lists do not need to understand the stored type.   Any operation which referes to an object in the linked list returns either a pointer to list_t or a pointer to void.
Any client is aware of the type it expects to be stored inside the linked list and can cast to the correct type when reading or cast to void pointer when writing.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a flexible array member instead of a `void *`, to more closely associate the data payload with the host struct.

Comment: @John Bollinger I see a conflict between OPs desire to use pure C (which I read as "no C++") and a "flexible array". That is because I hazely associate STL and other C++ concepts with that. Could you elaborate on the concept of flexile arrays in pure C?

Comment: Flexible array members are *only* a C feature (introduced in C99).  C++ does not have them.  They provide a standard alternative to a previous widespread but non-standard practice of declaring the last member of a struct as a one-char array, but allocating instances larger and intentionally overrunning the array bounds.  You can read a draft of the specifications for flexible array members [here](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p18).

Comment: @John Bollinger Thanks. I seem to be lagging behind with new C standards. In my job I am restricted to older standards.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the prototypes of your functions to -

```
void list_push(void *element, void *list_head);
void* list_pop(void *list_head);
void* list_next(void *list);
int list_length(void *list);
```

Now inside the function you can cast them as list_t* and list_t **

While calling them you can directly call them without any cast.

The only issue with this is that it will accept any pointer and you would lose error detection.

Comment: You do mean `void **list_head`, yes?

Comment: No, you can use void* because pointers to pointers can also be casted to void* without an explicit cast.

Comment: I am not sure if list_t** can be casted implicitly to void**. My guess is it can't be.

Answer (score 0):

> So my question: is there a way to assure the C compiler that `linked_buffer_t` and `pair_t` are a "a kind of" `list_t` so that I don't have to use casting every time I want to use list operations on them?

Your `linked_buffer_t` and `pair_t` *are not* kinds of `list_t` in any sense recognized by C semantics, so no, C does not provide any means to say that they are.  Moreover, the kind of pointer casting you propose to do will cause your program to violate the strict aliasing rule, and therefore to have undefined behavior.  In practice, though, the casting will work reliably in many places.  For example, POSIX relies on similar pointer casting in its socket API, so you can be fairly confident that that approach would work for you on such systems.

There nevertheless are ways to provide for generic lists in C.  You can get a measure of genericity with a union-based approach such as @dbush suggested.  You might also want to examine macro-based approaches such as the one in Troy Hanson's [UTHash](https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/utlist.html) package (which, although it is still distributed, is no longer maintained).

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya, yes, type punning by casting between incompatible pointer types (in the Standard's sense of "incompatible") violates a requirement of the standard, and therefore produces UB.  This is explicitly described in [paragraph 6.5/7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p7) of the standard, colloquially known as the "strict aliasing rule".

Comment: This seems correct. Offtopic but is it a special case that allows a variable to be read as a char by casting its pointer to char* ?

Comment: I ask this because that is the base of all byte wise copies.

Comment: Yes, @AjayBrahmakshatriya, if you read the provisions I linked for you, you will find that it is permissible to cast any valid object pointer to a pointer to a character type, and to read the bytes of the object's representation via that pointer.

Comment: Thanks, makes a lot more sense!

Answer (score 0):

We can exploit C11 6.7.2.1p15:

> A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

So, let's say you have

```
typedef  struct linked_list  linked_list;
struct linked_list {
    struct linked_list *next;
};
```

and all your linked list types start with a `linked_list common;` member:

```
struct list1 {
    linked_list  common;
    double       value;
};

struct list2 {
    linked_list  common;
    size_t       size;
    char         data[];
};

struct list3 {
    linked_list  common;
    /* ... other members ... */
};
```

For GCC, we can additionally use the `__typeof__` operator to set the return value to the proper type; for other compilers, the generic list functions will return a `void *`:

```
#define  LIST_NONE              ((void *)0)

#if defined(__gnuc__)
#define  LIST_NEXT(list)        ((__typeof__(list))(list_next(&((list)->common), (void *)(list))))
#define  LIST_SIZE(list)        (list_size(&((list)->common), (void *)(list)))
#define  LIST_PUSH(list, item)  (list_push((linked_list **)(list), &(*(list))->common, &((item)->common)))
#define  LIST_POP(list)         ((__typeof__(*(list)))list_pop((linked_list **)(list), &(*(list))->common))
#else
#define  LIST_NEXT(list)        ((void *)(list_next(&((list)->common), (void *)(list))))
#define  LIST_SIZE(list)        (list_size(&((list)->common), (void *)(list)))
#define  LIST_PUSH(list, item)  (list_push((linked_list **)(list), &(*(list))->common, &((item)->common)))
#define  LIST_POP(list)         ((void *)list_pop((linked_list **)(list), &(*(list))->common))
#endif
```

The `LIST_NONE` is a POSIX `NULL` macro. (That is, it is equivalent to `NULL` on POSIXy machines.)

The `LIST_SIZE()` and `LIST_NEXT()` macros take a single pointer as an argument. The macro assumes the pointer is to a structure type that has `linked_list common;` as the initial member and provides the address of that member, as well as the original pointer cast to a void pointer, to the corresponding function. Based on C11 6.7.2.1p15, the two should be equal.

If the pointer is to a type that is not a structure type, or the structure type lacks the `common` initial member, or that member is not a pointer to a `linked_list`, the compiler will issue an incompatible pointer type warning (if enabled).

If the `linked_list common;` is not the initial member in the structure, the two pointers supplied to the `list_size()` or `list_next()` functions will not match. You could use e.g. `assert()` from `<assert.h>` to check that:

```
linked_list *list_next(linked_list *list, void *copy)
{
    assert((void *)list == copy);
    return list->next;
}

size_t list_size(linked_list *list, void *copy)
{
    size_t result = 0;
    assert((void *)list == copy);
    while (list) {
        list = list->next;
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you feel you don't need to check that the `common` member is at the beginning of the structure, you can omit the `assert()` check, and the second parameter in the function calls (including in the macros) altogether.

The `LIST_PUSH()` and `LIST_POP()` macros are similar, but in this case we need a pointer to a pointer to the linked list member. Rather than try to cobble together some kind of address-of-address-of operator, we cast the pointer-to-pointer to pointer-to-pointer-to-`linked_list`, but also supply the address of the `common` member for type checking:

```
void list_push(linked_list **listptr, linked_list *list, linked_list *item)
{
    assert(list == *listptr);
    item->next = *listptr;
    *listptr = item;
}

linked_list *list_pop(linked_list **listptr, linked_list *list)
{
    assert(list == *listptr);
    if (*listptr) {
        linked_list *result = *listptr;
        *listptr = result->next;
        result->next = (linked_list *)0;
        return result;
    } else
        return (linked_list *)0;
}
```

In this case, if you feel you do not need to verify that the `common` member is at the beginning of the linked list structure type, you can omit the `assert()` check; however, you should not omit the `list` parameter in any case, because even if its value is not used, the compiler still checks its type.

Here is the full quickly-cobbled-together test program I used to verify the above:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef  struct linked_list  linked_list;
struct linked_list {
    struct linked_list *next;
};

struct list1 {
    linked_list  common;
    double       value;
};

struct list2 {
    linked_list  common;
    size_t       size;
    char         data[];
};

struct list3 {
    linked_list  common;
    /* ... other members ... */
};

static inline void list_push(linked_list **listptr, linked_list *list, linked_list *item)
{
    assert(list == *listptr);
    item->next = *listptr;
    *listptr = item;
}

static inline linked_list *list_pop(linked_list **listptr, linked_list *list)
{
    assert(list == *listptr);
    if (*listptr) {
        linked_list *result = *listptr;
        *listptr = result->next;
        result->next = (linked_list *)0;
        return result;
    } else
        return (linked_list *)0;
}

static inline linked_list *list_next(linked_list *list, void *copy)
{
    assert((void *)list == copy);
    return list->next;
}

static inline size_t list_size(linked_list *list, void *copy)
{
    size_t result = 0;
    assert((void *)list == copy);
    while (list) {
        list = list->next;
        result++;
    }
    return result;
}

#if defined(__gnuc__)
#define  LIST_NEXT(list)        ((__typeof__(list))(list_next(&((list)->common), (void *)(list))))
#define  LIST_SIZE(list)        (list_size(&((list)->common), (void *)(list)))
#define  LIST_PUSH(list, item)  (list_push((linked_list **)(list), &(*(list))->common, &((item)->common)))
#define  LIST_POP(list)         ((__typeof__(*(list)))list_pop((linked_list **)(list), &(*(list))->common))
#else
#define  LIST_NEXT(list)        ((void *)(list_next(&((list)->common), (void *)(list))))
#define  LIST_SIZE(list)        (list_size(&((list)->common), (void *)(list)))
#define  LIST_PUSH(list, item)  (list_push((linked_list **)(list), &(*(list))->common, &((item)->common)))
#define  LIST_POP(list)         ((void *)list_pop((linked_list **)(list), &(*(list))->common))
#endif

void test_list1(void)
{
    struct list1  a, b, c, *root = NULL;
    size_t n;

    a.value = 1.0; LIST_PUSH(&root, &a);
    b.value = 2.0; LIST_PUSH(&root, &b);
    c.value = 3.0; LIST_PUSH(&root, &c);

    n = LIST_SIZE(root);
    if (n == 3)
        printf("test_list1(): list_size() OK\n");
    else
        printf("test_list1(): list_size() == %zu, ERROR\n", n);

    if (LIST_POP(&root) != &c)
        printf("test_list1(): list_pop() ERROR");
    else
    if (LIST_POP(&root) != &b)
        printf("test_list1(): list_pop() ERROR");
    else
    if (LIST_POP(&root) != &a)
        printf("test_list1(): list_pop() ERROR");
    else
    if (root)
        printf("test_list1(): list_pop() ERROR");
    else
        printf("test_list1(): list_pop() OK\n");
}

void test_list2(void)
{
    struct list2  a, b, c, *root = NULL;
    size_t n;

    a.size = 1; LIST_PUSH(&root, &a);
    b.size = 2; LIST_PUSH(&root, &b);
    c.size = 3; LIST_PUSH(&root, &c);

    n = LIST_SIZE(root);
    if (n == 3)
        printf("test_list2(): list_size() OK\n");
    else
        printf("test_list2(): list_size() == %zu, ERROR\n", n);

    if (LIST_POP(&root) != &c)
        printf("test_list2(): list_pop() ERROR");
    else
    if (LIST_POP(&root) != &b)
        printf("test_list2(): list_pop() ERROR");
    else
    if (LIST_POP(&root) != &a)
        printf("test_list2(): list_pop() ERROR");
    else
    if (root)
        printf("test_list2(): list_pop() ERROR");
    else
        printf("test_list2(): list_pop() OK\n");
}

void test_list3(void)
{
    struct list3 a, b, c, *root = NULL;
    size_t n;

    LIST_PUSH(&root, &a);
    LIST_PUSH(&root, &b);
    LIST_PUSH(&root, &c);

    n = LIST_SIZE(root);
    if (n == 3)
        printf("test_list3(): list_size() OK\n");
    else
        printf("test_list3(): list_size() == %zu, ERROR\n", n);

    if (LIST_POP(&root) != &c)
        printf("test_list3(): list_pop() ERROR");
    else
    if (LIST_POP(&root) != &b)
        printf("test_list3(): list_pop() ERROR");
    else
    if (LIST_POP(&root) != &a)
        printf("test_list3(): list_pop() ERROR");
    else
    if (root)
        printf("test_list3(): list_pop() ERROR");
    else
        printf("test_list3(): list_pop() OK\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    test_list1();
    test_list2();
    test_list3();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that since I only use the functions in this single compilation unit, I marked the list accessor functions `static inline`. This should let the compiler optimize away the extra function parameter, and overall generate better code. If you use these functions in several compilation units, I'd probably just keep the `static inline` and let the compiler generate the duplicates, unless code size is an issue.

Since I use GCC, I compiled and ran the above `list.c` using

```
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic list.c -o test && ./test
```

If you find a bug in the above, or a reason why you think I've misinterpreted the C11 standard, please let me know in the comments so I can verify.